# Почему subprocess не работает с кавычками?

Tags: python, cmd

Хочу через Python выполнить какую-нить команду в командной строке Windows (cmd), к примеру если выполнить tasklist без каких либо параметров, то все нормально работает:

```
subprocess.call(['tasklist'])
```

Но если добавить кавычки в параметры, то ничего не работает:

```
subprocess.call(['tasklist','/fi','"sessionname eq Console"'])
```

Собственно выполняю такой код:

```
import subprocess as sp

var_command = raw_input('Enter command: ')

proc = sp.Popen(var_command.split(),stdout=sp.PIPE,stderr=sp.PIPE)

out, error = proc.communicate()
print out
```

С чем это может быть связно? Причем если кавычек в параметрах нет, то также все нормально работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если `args` является последовательностью и `shell=False` (по умолчанию), то `subprocess` сам экранирует все аргументы. Т.е. в вашем примере будет выполнено:

```
tasklist /fi "\"sessionname eq Console\""
```

[Subprocess management. Frequently Used Arguments](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#frequently-used-arguments)

[Converting an argument sequence to a string on Windows](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#converting-an-argument-sequence-to-a-string-on-windows)

Answer (score 1):

[Интересная особенность использования subprocess](http://asvetlov.blogspot.ru/2011/03/subprocess.html)

Comment: Спасибо, суть работы subprocess понял, но насчет кавычек так и не прояснилось.